# OSX can't do passwordless localhost ssh

Tags: ssh, macos

I've just searched around and couldn't find any solution so here's my problem:

On my OSX 10.7.4 I'm trying to set up a passwordless localhost ssh by `ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa` & `cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` but `ssh localhost` keeps asking for the password. I deleted all lines in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and started over but nothing changed, it still asks. What should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Look at this: http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/25/how-to-set-up-a-password-less-ssh-login/

Comment: I had already seen that page and applied it but no change.

Comment: Post the output of 'ssh -v localhost'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use DSA keys. They are fixed 1024 bits and not secure enough today. Generate a new RSA key and your steps should work:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If the RSA does not work either, most probably there will be a problem with permissions (which is in the debug log of the server). Make sure that your home directory, the `~/.ssh/` and `authorized_keys` files are owned by you and not writable by any other user/group.

Comment: Hello I had already tried the RSA option but it made no difference.

Comment: So then try with the debug log on server and client and post the logs, because without them it is only guessing what could go wrong (permissions, and so on).

Comment: Hello looking at the Console.app's output filtered by ssh, this line was present: `Jun 10 15:13:06 dreamy-Mac-mini sshd[57227]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /Users/dreamy` Permission was 777 I did `chmod 755 /Users/dreamy`and it started to work without any further action. If you edit the answer accordingly, I'll select it as a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have incorrect permissions on your `authorized_keys` file. using a verbose logging on both client and server would reveal it. Also you could have incorrect permisions on your `~/.ssh` directory. Both should be owned by the users and users-home-group and should only be readable by the user (the directory also needs execute pemrmission) and only writeable by the user.

So you would get something like this:

- `drwx------ ~/.ssh`
- `-rw------- ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

This also applies to your private key on your client.

Comment: Hello as you guessed it was a permissions problem. On the log output I saw ssh check the users dir permissions and because my dir was 777, so it was asking for the password. Changing it to 755 solved the problem.

Comment: For anyone coming here trying to understand where the permissions issue originates, I'm posting here because it took me quite a bit of searches to find it myself. This is enforced by the [`StrictModes`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#StrictModes) setting in `sshd_config`. It's not recommended to disable, but it is helpful for troubleshooting.